# Capture virtual machine traffic in Fiddler

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, http, traffic, fiddler

I'm running Ubuntu in a virtual machine (host machine is Windows 7). Is it possible to use Fiddler in the host machine to capture the traffic from the virtual machine? Seeing as the virtual machine's network must be passing through the host computers NIC, can Fiddler capture the packets? (I don't know of any free alternative to Fiddler for Linux, except Tamper Data, but I need a bit more control). Thanks.

Comment: For the record, WebScarab is a pretty good alternative to Fiddler. Also check out Burp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite a few alternatives for Fiddler on Linux, some that I would even consider **better**. Two that come to mind are [**Nettool**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nettool/) and [**Paros**](http://www.parosproxy.org/) (Paros Proxy). Both are Java based (multiplatform) and Paros is my personal preference.

Answer (score 12):

It is possible. The following steps worked for me with Windows 7 Enterprise running Ubuntu 10 in VMWare Player 4.0.1

1. In Ubuntu VM visit the Network Proxy dialog (System > Preferences > Network Proxy)
2. Select "Manual proxy configuration"
3. Enter host (Windows) IP addresss and port 8888 (unless you have changed that default in Fiddler)
4. Close dialog
5. Open Fiddler options, select the Connections tab, ensure that "Allow remote computers to connect" is enabled. If it's not, enable it and restart Fiddler.

Comment: works fine for virtual box as well, be sure to listen all processes on host though

Comment: What about https? Can it intercept that?